# Count the number of missing values in R

Tags: r

I'm working with Pima Indians Diabetes data from Kaggle in **Rstudio** and instead of na's as missing values it has 0s.
How can I count the number of "0" values in each variable with a **single loop** instead of typing `table(data$variableName==0)` for each column. Just rephrasing ,"**a single loop for the whole data frame**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `colSums` on a logical `matrix`

```
colSums(data == 0)
```

---

Or with `sapply` in a loop

```
sapply(data, function(x) sum(x == 0))
```

or with `apply`

```
apply(data, 2, function(x) sum(x == 0))
```

Or in a `for` loop

```
count <- numeric(ncol(data))
for(i in seq_along(data))  count[i] <- sum(data[[i]] == 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I got it right using the code you suggested.Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% summarise(across(.fns = ~sum(.==0,na.rm=TRUE) ,.names = "Zeros_in_{.col}"))
```